# Redux store namespaced actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have react component using redux. It's a view with a sidebar and a main view area.

Whenever I want to create a new view I can inherit this base view. All possible actions are shared in the reducer.

The only problem is when an action is dispatched I need to namespace the action so the store has a little more context on which view called the action. Even though the action types are the same.

I was thinking I could have an array of views and use this to loop the action types with a dynamic namespace. I think my syntax is wrong. Or my thinking is wrong.

I was thinking I could loop a switch case - I know this will now return multiple states overriding itself. So obviously not good.

Open to thoughts on how to handle this operation cleanly.

```
const views = [{name: 'visitor', actionName: 'VISITOR'},{name: 'action', actionName: 'ACTION'}]

const reducer = (state, action) => {

  views.forEach((view, i) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        // View Actions
        case view.actionName + '_VIEW_LOADED':
          return {
            ...state,
            ['open_' + view.name + '_view']: true,
            [view.name + '_props']: action[view.name + '_view_data']
          }

        default:
            return state;

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you attach the view name as part of the action? I don't totally get why you're doing this but it seems like it'd be a lot more extensible and fairly easy to just pass it as an arg to your action.

Comment: Hmm maybe you're right. There was a reason I did it this way I think. Perhaps I should rethink it haha

Comment: I would say the reason I didnt do this is not because of the action but the state itself. I guess I could add it as an arg and use that arg to define the key of the state. Good idea....

Comment: Would certainly save you from having to use `const views` in each of your reducers

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect time to argue for composition over inheritance. If this  concept is totally new to you, go watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfMtDGfHWpA).

It sounds to me like your common view component should be a child (perhaps the only child) of your other components that would "extend" it. Then you can pass in on props the specific action creators that the common view component should use.

```
/* Common View Component */
class CommonSplitView extends React.Component {
...
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onCloseDetailView}>Close</button>
      <button onClick={this.props.onOpenDetailView}>Open</button>
    );
  }
}
CommonSplitView.propTypes = {
  onCloseDetailView: React.PropTypes.func,
  onOpenDetailView: React.PropTypes.func
}

/* Component that extends the common view component */
class ProfileView extends React.Component {
...
  render() {
    return (
      <CommonSplitView
        onCloseDetailView={this.props.onCloseDetails}
        onOpenDetailView={this.props.onOpenDetails}
      />
    );
  }
 }
 ...
 const mapStateToProps = state => state;
 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   onCloseDetails: () => { dispatch(<something specific to ProfileView>) },
   onOpenDetails: () => { dispatch(<something specific to ProfileView>) }
 });
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileView);
```

Ta da! Just like that, now your common view component (in this example CommonSplitView) dispatches actions specific to ProfileView. Pretty neat, right? This is called *inversion of control*.  From the parent component, I inject the methods I want CommonSplitView to call when the Close and Open buttons are hit.  Turns out this pattern is very handy just about everywhere.

Hopefully this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Why would you need a separate ProfileView class?

It would be sufficient to export the component that gets out of `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CommonSplitView)`.